# How to filter files in llvm-cov code coverage report?

Tags: xcode, bash, code-coverage, llvm-cov

From the [llvm-cov docs](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html#llvm-cov-show):

> `llvm-cov show [options] -instr-profile PROFILE BIN [-object BIN,...] [[-object BIN]] [SOURCES]`
>
> The llvm-cov show command shows line by line coverage of the binaries
>   BIN,... using the profile data PROFILE. It can optionally be filtered
>   to only show the coverage for the files listed in SOURCES.

I'm using the following command:

`xcrun llvm-cov show -instr-profile "${PROFDATA}" "${BINARY}" codecov_source_files > Coverage.report`

Where `codecov_source_files` is a file with this line:

> `*Router.swift`

So basically what I want is the report to only contain files with the suffix: `Router.swift`

But i'm getting a Coverage.report with all the classes in the project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's badly worded but `SOURCES` is actually a list of file names, not the name of a file containing a list of filenames.

They need to be the paths to the actual source files on disk. It doesn't support wildcards or regex unfortunately.

Edit: By reading the source I have discovered that you can also list directories as `SOURCES` and it will recurse into them. Also there is an undocumented option `-dump-collected-paths` which prints the files the `SOURCES` match.

Comment: Thank you for finding out `SOURCES` could be a folder. That really should be documented. Here is a full example of this for others that was tested with Clang 4.0. It will only show coverage for files in the `src_dir` folder. `llvm-cov show -format=html -instr-profile=default.profdata my_exe src_dir/ > coverage.html`

Comment: You also might want to use `-output-dir=PATH` instead of `> coverage.html`.  I don't believe the latter gives you per-file outputs.

Comment: Thank you @Timmmm, the `-output-dir` argument is MUCH nicer!

Answer (score 2):

- you can use help to look up supported commands

```
$ llvm-cov show --help
$ llvm-cov report --help
```

- Maybe the following command is the function you want

```
 --ignore-filename-regex=<string> - Skip source code files with file paths that match the given regular expression
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).